# Discrepancy in t-test Results between Python and Matlab with Identical Data: Mean Calculation Precision Issue? How to modify it?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, t-test

I have two sets of numbers a and b, where a is (11, 1) and b is (46, 1).
All the numbers in a and b are the same.

Here are the specific values:

```
0.0435390887054011854750967813743045553565025329589843750
```

However, when I subtract the averages of the two sets of numbers, two completely different results appear in matlab and python:

**Matlab:**

```
a = repmat(0.0435390887054011854750967813743045553565025329589843750, 1, 11);
b = repmat(0.0435390887054011854750967813743045553565025329589843750, 1, 46);
mean(a)-mean(b)
```

**Output:**

```
ans = 0
```

**Python:**

```
a = np.array([0.0435390887054011854750967813743045553565025329589843750] * 11, dtype=np.float64)
b = np.array([0.0435390887054011854750967813743045553565025329589843750] * 46, dtype=np.float64)
np.mean(a)-np.mean(b)
```

**Output:**

```
-6.938893903907228e-18
```

In fact, the averages of the two groups are the same, and the result should be 0. The python result obviously produced an error.

Taking into account the error of floating point numbers, if the array is converted to decimal form, python can correctly output 0. However, converting to decimal will increase the operation time sharply.

Is there a better way to improve it?

In fact, this problem was discovered when trying a two-sample t-test. The t-test was performed on the above a and b, and different results were obtained in matlab and python:

**Matlab:**

```
[tad,p_tmp] = ttest2(a, b)
```

**Output:**

```
tad = NaN
p_tmp = NaN
```

**Python:**

```
_, p_tmp = ttest_ind(a, b)
```

**Output：**

```
p_tmp = 0.001731693698230969
```

Among them, I conducted experiments on some other similar arrays. Matlab outputs NAN or 1, while python approximates some very small numbers.

Through debugging, I found that the problem occurred: **"mean(a)-mean(b) operation"** was performed in ttest_ind of scipy.stats.

If **"mean(a)-mean(b)"** is 0, then p=1. However, as mentioned before, **"mean(a)-mean(b)"** is in gives a non-zero result in python.

I also tried other libraries for python, such as statsmodels.stats.weightstats and pingouin, but all produced similar situations

---

In addition, I also discovered another problem.
If there are two feature matrices "X1" and "X2", corresponding to the positive and negative data respectively, where: X1 is (11, 906), and X2 is (46, 906)

Assuming that "c" and "d" are one of the sets of numbers, then whether the t test is performed on them individually or the t test is performed on the entire matrix, the corresponding p values in matlab are the same, but different results are produced in python.

Let’s give a simple example: assuming "c" and "d" are the data in column 420, then there is:

```
ttest_ind(c, d)
pvalue = 1.1031870941764164e-09

_, pvalue = ttest_ind(X1, X2)
pvalue[420] = 8.819570120388648e-09
```

However, in either case in matlab, the final result is:

```
pvalue = 8.819570120388648e-09
```

Why does this difference occur? How to make the results of two situations consistent in python?

Comment: 7e-18 is tiny compared to your data values: it's 16 orders of magnitude smaller. Wouldn't you regard it as zero for all intents and purposes?

Comment: There is also another set of features, and the difference between their average values is of the order of 1e-20, because this set of data itself is smaller. However, the difference between the two sets of data is very large, so it was retained in the t test. and they are also very useful features

If 1e-17 is treated as 0, then other smaller features will also be treated as having no difference

Comment: Maybe what you care about is something like `(np.mean(a) - np.mean(b)) / np.mean(a)`? That will be very small (~2e-16) for your data here, but not necessarily for your numerically smaller data set.

Comment: Regarding the t-test: your dataset here has zero variance, so in a sense `NAN` is the "right" answer. But it will be very sensitive to precision issues. If you really have a dataset like this, it's not clear that a t-test is meaningful.

Comment: Thanks, (np.mean(a) - np.mean(b)) / np.mean(a) may work, I'll try it.
This problem is that I tensorized a set of data and achieved an accuracy of 96% in matlab. However, when I reproduced it in python, I found that the results of t test were different from matlab.

Comment: Right - the problem is that this is a really pathological set of data as far as the t-test is concerned (zero variance, and identical mean in both samples). The t-test essentially asks "do these samples represent two populations with truly different means, or is the difference in means explained by random variance"? It's going to be unstable when the difference in means, and the variance, are both tiny compared to the datapoints, and the result is undefined if the variance and the difference in means are both zero.

Comment: Scipy gives you a `RuntimeWarning: Precision loss occurred in moment calculation due to catastrophic cancellation. This occurs when the data are nearly identical. Results may be unreliable` if you run your example.

Comment: That's right, because the mean and variance of the two sets of data are same, t-test cannot be performed, so matlab chooses to output the p value as NAN or 1, so that these data will not be passed. However, python outputs 0.0017, which means that even if you choose p=0.01, it can also pass the t-test.